# IE11, bootstrap 4, inline form problem: collapse input inside input-group

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

How to solve the collapsed input inside `input-goup` inside `inline-form` ?

**Chrome:**

[image]

**IE11:**

[image]

I can't understand where to dig: IE11 support `flex`'es (base of `form-inline`)

Code:

```
<div class="form-inline mb-4">
   <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">@</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="my text" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Snippet: https://dashboardcode.github.io/BsMultiSelect/snippetBsInlineGroup.html

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29987

Comment: Thank you, strange that adding inline `style="width: 1%;"` of `style="flex: 1 1 auto;  width: 1%;"` doesn't solve it... (to `input`)